# Random Recipe Generator in Python

Tags: python

I have to create a random recipe generator in Python. Here are the design specifications:

- At least 25 different ingredients and 10 different “cooking phrases” to draw from.
- Recipes consist of an ingredient list and a description of the process. The process should mention the same ingredients that are in the list.
- Randomly generate amounts for the ingredients as well as the ingredient names. When in doubt, measure everything in grams.
- Organize your program into functions. You should have at least 2 user-defined functions.

I have written some code but I am having trouble with using the same randomly generated ingredients and adding them to the end of the "recipe instructions" sentences.

```
import random

def ingredients_list(quantity, ing):
    quantity = random.choice(amounts)
    ing = random.choice(ingredients)
    return("{} {}".format(quantity, ing))
    
def recipe_instructions(recipe):
    recipe = random.choice(cooking_phrases)
    return("{}".format(recipe))
    
amounts = ["50g", "70g", "90g", "143g", "150g", "180g", "200g", "235g", "300g", "320g", "350g", "386g", "400g", "433g", "462g"]
ingredients = ["eggs", "sugar", "salt", "butter", "milk", "bacon", "tomatoes", "pasta", "rice", "potatoes", "onions", "carrots", "all-purpose flour", "noodles", "cheese", "chicken", "beef", "spinach", "strawberries", "apples", "blueberries", "olive oil", "soy sauce", "corn", "shrimp", "mayonnaise"]
cooking_phrases = ["In a medium sized bowl, whisk together the", "In a large skillet over medium heat, stir-fry the", "In a skillet, Sauté the", "In a large pot, boil the", "Thoroughly wash the", "Thinly slice the", "Make small, 1-inch cubes by dicing up the", "Set the timer for 1 minute and microwave the", "Using a blender, thoroughly blend the",  "For 20 minutes in a 350°F oven, bake the"]


quantity = random.choice(amounts)
ing = random.choice(ingredients)
recipe = random.choice(cooking_phrases)

for i in range(5):
    print(ingredients_list(quantity, ing))

print ("Recipe Instructions:")
for i in range(5):
    print(recipe_instructions(recipe) + " " + ing)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "having trouble"? Give a [mre].

Comment: Where is your issue? Do you have an error to show? There is some bad code practice, you are using global constants into your functions (such as `random.choice(amounts)`). Either pass it as argument to the function or make it clear that they are global constants.

Comment: It will be better if you can include the result you get now and the result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the ingredients with `random.sample()` instead of `random.choice()`, you get a list of unique ingredient without duplicates. See the example below:

```
import random

def ingredients_list(quantity, ing):
    quantity = random.choice(amounts)
    # ing = random.choice(ingredients) This one can generate duplicates
    return("{} {}".format(quantity, ing))
    
def recipe_instructions(recipe):
    recipe = random.choice(cooking_phrases)
    return("{}".format(recipe))
    
amounts = ["50g", "70g", "90g", "143g", "150g", "180g", "200g", "235g", "300g", "320g", "350g", "386g", "400g", "433g", "462g"]
ingredients = ["eggs", "sugar", "salt", "butter", "milk", "bacon", "tomatoes", "pasta", "rice", "potatoes", "onions", "carrots", "all-purpose flour", "noodles", "cheese", "chicken", "beef", "spinach", "strawberries", "apples", "blueberries", "olive oil", "soy sauce", "corn", "shrimp", "mayonnaise"]
cooking_phrases = ["In a medium sized bowl, whisk together the", "In a large skillet over medium heat, stir-fry the", "In a skillet, Sauté the", "In a large pot, boil the", "Thoroughly wash the", "Thinly slice the", "Make small, 1-inch cubes by dicing up the", "Set the timer for 1 minute and microwave the", "Using a blender, thoroughly blend the",  "For 20 minutes in a 350°F oven, bake the"]

steps = 5

quantity = random.choice(amounts)
ings = random.sample(ingredients, k=steps) # use random.sample to generate unique ingredients and prevent duplicates
recipe = random.choice(cooking_phrases)

for i in range(steps):
    ing = ings[i]
    print(ingredients_list(quantity, ing))

print ("Recipe Instructions:")
for i in range(steps):
    ing = ings[i]
    print(recipe_instructions(recipe) + " " + ing)
```